# How to access a record's field in an Execute sentence?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to access a dynamic field from a dynamic table, and I have this code for doing this

Here f_field takes the name of a column from t_table dynamicly.

When t_table is declared as a record this code gets an error. But when declared as a static column fieldType it runs as expected.

The question is, How can I declared t_row for this code to run properly, or how can I achieve the same by other way. Remember that t_table and f_field are dynamic and therefore their values change.

```
FOR t_row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * from ' || t_table loop
    EXECUTE format('select $1.%I', f_field) USING t_row into f;
    RAISE notice '%', f;
  END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was doing my research I found out that sentences like EXECUTE... doesn't understand records structure, this was by experimenting with plpgsql because there is not doc about this. So I need to convert t_row in another kind of object that has methods to extract a value from a dynamic field, I chose json because I think it is easy to use. This is my code.

```
FOR t_row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * from dd.a' loop
   f_json := row_to_json(layer_row);
   f := json_extract_path(f_json, f_field);
   RAISE notice '%', f;
END LOOP;
```

It work for fine for me, but this is only a walkaround, if someone could point out why is my first code not working I will apreciate it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if I get your task right, you dont need `$1` and `USING` here at all, eg:

```
do
$$
declare
 t_table text;
 f text;
 f_field text := 'oid';
 r record;
begin
 for r in (select relname from pg_class where relname = 'pg_database') loop
  EXECUTE format('select %I from %I', f_field, r.relname) into f;
  RAISE notice '%', f;
 end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

mind it raises only first row out of many this way

```
NOTICE:  12669
DO
```

Comment: remember the name of the table is dynamic as well as f_field